# Text area validation in javascript for html image tag

Tags: javascript, html, image

I want to validate a text area for img tag when it is duplicated. example, if i entered the image tag with src   i should enter the same source with tag again i need to show alert how it could be done. my snippet to check whether the image is there or not. but i need to do for above validation also...

```
function validateEditor() {

    var editor_val = $('#asset_html').val(), iSrc;

    // Check for empty string
    if(!string_IsEmpty(editor_val)) { 

        // Check whether img is available
        if(editor_val.match(/img/g)) {

            var src_cnt = (editor_val.match(/img/g).length);
            //console.log(editor_val.match(/src/g).length);

            $('#asset_html_preview').html(editor_val);

            for(var j = 1; j <= src_cnt; j++) {

                if($('#asset_html_preview img:nth-child(1)').attr('src')) {

                    iSrc = $('#asset_html_preview img:nth-child(1)').attr('src');

                    if(iSrc.indexOf('http://') != -1) { 

                        $('#asset_html_preview img:nth-child(' + j + ')')
                            .error(function() { alert('Check ur image src'); });
                        //break;

                    } 
                }
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: @ Shreekhanal edited plz check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be looking for this:

```
var arr = {};
var $div = $('<div />').html($('textarea').val());
$div.find('img').each(function (i) {
        var src = $(this).attr('src');

        if (src.indexOf('http://') >= 0 && arr[src] == undefined) {
           arr[src] = 'foobar';
        } else if (arr[src] !== undefined) {
           alert('This url `' + src + '` already exists');     
        } else {
           alert('This url `' + src + '` is wrong');     
        }  
 });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LXgWU/3/

Comment: @codefOrmer it is validating only the img tag...but i need to validate like if two img tag entered with same source name a alert should be given

Comment: that also can be done. You should put the image url into an js array and check if it exists (show an error message) before adding into the array.

Comment: another doubt also man....eg: i uploaded an image with random name in my server and if i try to upload the same image again how will i check that this image has been uploaded or not........

Comment: If you do not rename the image while uploading then you should keep the image names in database and should check if any image exists in the DB before uploading it.

Comment: I have one issue like i am uploading an image but the image name is changing after going to server how to upload with same name via php...show some example...

Comment: I recommend, you should not do that because 1.jpg image may be a cat pic for you but for me it could be a dog pic.

Comment: Just remove the code which does the renaming. I think, when you post the image, you could get the original name. In php, its something like `$_FILES["file"]["name"]`

Comment: ya ... move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$dirname."/".$_FILES["file"]["name"].".jpg");....wh should be removed here.....

Comment: this should upload the image without renaming its name. Do you see 1.jpg stored in your uploads directory when you browse and upload 1.jpg or if not what does it rename in to?

Comment: when i click a browse button that time itself the name is coming as 1.jpg so only in server also like that...u have gmail account send plz...i need to fix this issue.....

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `var src_cnt` work perfect.

```
var src_cnt = (editor_val.match(/img/g).length);
if(src_cnt == 1)
{
alert("Plz choose Unique Image");
return false;
}
```